# как удалить выбранное превью , извлечь массив

Tags: javascript, jquery, файлы

Не могу понять как и File Reader удалить выбранное , не могу извлечь массив

```js
function previewFiles() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
  var files = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if (/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var image = new Image();
        image.height = 100;
        image.title = file.name;
        image.src = this.result;
        preview.appendChild(image);
      }, false);

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

  }

  if (files) {
    [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
  }

}
$('#delete').bind("click", function() {




  //Проблема тут

  $('#preview').hide(); // Удаляем превью
  $('#preview').replaceWith($('#photo').clone());


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preview"></div>
<br>
<input type="file" class="photo" id="browse" name="photo" onchange="previewFiles()" multiple/>

<div id="delete">delete</div>
```

Comment: изменил код, или вы имеете виду писать отдельно функцию которая у ищет массив и удаляет превью

Comment: этот вопрос был, не могу найти

Comment: найдите просто все просмотрел нет нигде

Comment: непонятно что именно надо удалить и какой массив куда извлечь. Чем не нравится текущее решение?

Comment: решение удаляет сразу все изображения а если пользователь загрузил 5 изображений а удалит хочет 2 и 3

Comment: @Koly, удалить можно только превьюшки, при этом надпись в инпуте с числом выбранных файлов - не поменяется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Список загружаемых файлов нельзя изменить из javaScript. [`FileList`](http://www.element-it.com/ru/multiple-file-upload/flash-uploader.aspx) доступен только для чтения. Операции с локальными файлами сильно ограничены в целях безопасности.

Поэтому, вам нужно создать отдельный массив, в который вы сможете складывать файлы из `FileList`.

```js
var filestoupload = [];
function previewFiles() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
  var files = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if (/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var image = new Image();
        image.height = 100;
        image.title = file.name;
        image.src = this.result;
        filestoupload.push(this.result)
        var div= document.createElement('div');
        var divdel= document.createElement('div');
        divdel.className='delete'
        divdel.innerHTML='delete'
        div.className='fileprew'
        div.appendChild(divdel);
        div.appendChild(image);
        preview.appendChild(div);
        console.log('files to upload: ', filestoupload.length)
        
      }, false);

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

  }

  if (files) {
    [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
    
  }

}
$('body').on("click", ".delete", function() {
  
  index=$(this).index();
  console.log('удаляем файл: ',index)
  filestoupload.splice(index, 1);
  $(this).parent().remove();
  console.log('files to upload: ', filestoupload.length)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preview"></div>
<br>
<input type="file" class="photo" id="browse" name="photo" onchange="previewFiles()" multiple/>
```